# Incorrect Stored Procedure Syntax

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I am using the below stored procedure to upload files into a db where each file has a correspondence table but there are times when the table not exist in that case i want to add the file name into a table called NewTables.I can not get the stored proc syntax working can someone help me.I believe the mistake is in the first part where i check if the table exist

```
 ALTER proc [dbo].[UploadCSVFiles]

   @FilePath varchar(100) ,
   @FileName varchar(100),  
   @TableName varchar(250)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SqlStmt nvarchar(max) 
DECLARE @ErrorCode int

SET @SqlStmt='Truncate table dbo.[' + @TableName +']'
EXEC(@SqlStmt);
set @SqlStmt =N' 
IF  not EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].['+@TableName +N']'') AND type in (N''U''))
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO dbo.NewTables ('+@TableName+N','+@FileName+N') Values('+@TableName+N','+@FileName+N')


  END 
ELSE 
  BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO '+@TableName+N'
select *
from openrowset(''MSDASQL''
               ,''Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}; 
                    DefaultDir='+@FilePath+N'''
               ,''select * from "'+@FileName+N'"'')

  END
  '
  EXEC(@SqlStmt);
```

Thanks
Rao

Thanks fpop and Christine, I have made the suggestions you made but still I get an error

```
Msg 4701, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find the object "Customer" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

it seems the If statement does not insert the new table

here is the final version

```
USE [MyDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

  ALTER proc [dbo].[UploadFiles_2]

  @FilePath varchar(100) ,
  @FileName varchar(100),  
  @TableName varchar(250)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SqlStmt nvarchar(max) 
DECLARE @ErrorCode int

SET @SqlStmt='Truncate table dbo.[' + @TableName +']'
EXEC sp_executesql @SqlStmt;
set @SqlStmt =N' 
IF ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].['+@TableName +N']'') AND type in (N''U''))
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO dbo.NewTables (TableName,FileName) Values('''+@TableName+N''','''+@FileName+N''')    

  END 
ELSE 
  BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO '+@TableName+N'
    select *
    from openrowset(''MSDASQL''
               ,''Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}; 
                    DefaultDir='+@FilePath+N'''
               ,''select * from "'+@FileName+N'"'')

  END'

   EXEC sp_executesql @SqlStmt;

 END
```

Comment: Hi, do you have an error you can post?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can always add PRINT @SQLSTMT to see the code your procedure has generated.

There are two error in the script, both in line:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.NewTables ('+@TableName+N','+@FileName+N') Values('+@TableName+N','+@FileName+N')
```

First error: NewTables table must have 2 columns to keep table name and file name. Let's call them COL_TBL, COL_FILE

Second error: You have to add quotes in Values part of statement

Here is how it should look like:

```
    INSERT INTO dbo.NewTables (COL_TBL, COL_FILE) Values('''+@TableName+N''','''+@FileName+N''')
```

btw, You didn't post code entirely, there is an END at the end missing. Please, next time copy the whole code so others can reproduce the error.

EDIT: Please consider following: using sp_executesql instead of EXEC, to avoid sql injection bugs do not concatenate parameters into dynamic sql and finally check if table exists before truncating it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE [type] LIKE 'U' AND name LIKE 'mytable')) 
    SELECT 'not found';
ELSE
    SELECT 'found';
```

Comment: that was written for sql2008r2 by the way

Comment: the whole point of the OP's syntax problems was to pass in the table as a variable, you have it as a literal.  In your code, replace `name LIKE 'mytable'` with `object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].['+@TableName +N']')` and then it will work on a variable.